# Simplify $\int_0^{\infty}\,dk\,\exp{(-\delta^2k^2)}\,J_1(kR)\frac{1}{1+bk^2}$

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions

EDIT:

I would love to find an analytical solution for this definite integral:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\,dk\,\exp{(-\delta^2k^2)}\,J_1(kR)\frac{1}{1+bk^2}$$

with $\delta>0,\, R>0,\,b>0$.

Does anyone can help me? I tried to have a look at Gradshteyn and Ryzhik, without any success.

Thanks

Comment: The $1/(1+bk^\alpha)$ term makes it hard to solve. If $\alpha=0$ then its much easier and a (elementary) analytical solution can be found ($1 - \frac{e^{-\left(\frac{R}{2 \delta}\right)^2}}{R}$).

Comment: If only two functions among $\exp(-s^2),J_1(s),\frac{1}{1+|s|^{\alpha}}$ would have been there, the problem were feasible to a Fourier transform approach. In this form, I would not bet that a nice closed form exists.

Comment: @Winther Thanks. I have now restricted the integral to $\alpha=2$. Can you help now?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio what about the residue theorem now that $\alpha=2$?

Comment: I don't think that helps, at least I don't see any way to solve it. I tried to check it with mathematical software and it failed to find a solution (which does not rule out anything, but it makes it less plausible), but if you remove any of the three factors (as Jack mentioned above) then closed form solutions does exist.